# Load database Field Values to A JCombobox

Tags: java, oracle, swing, jdbc, jcombobox

How to load values from an Oracle db to a JComboBox to make it easier for the user To Choose from I Have tried this:

```
    Connection dbcon = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        dbcon = DriverManager.getConnection("
             jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
        Statement st = dbcon.createStatement();
        String combo = "Select EMP_IDNUM from employees";
        ResultSet res = st.executeQuery(combo);
        while(res.next()){
            String ids = res.getString("EMP_IDNUM");
            String [] str = new String[]{ids};
            cboId = new JComboBox(str);
        }
    } catch (Exception d) {
        System.out.println(d);
    }
```

This is Only getting me the first Value Into the JComboBox cboID. What Is the Best way to Load the entire Field Data (EMP_IDNUM) into the Jcombobox??

Comment: I cannot believe someone was "Good Enough" DOwnvote My question Whle I was Just Askng..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String [] str = new String[]{ids};
```

It means your String array is having only one ids value which you have  loaded `String ids = res.getString("EMP_IDNUM");`

```
if(rs.getRow()>0){
 String [] str = new String[res.getRow()];
 int i=0;
 while(res.next()){
   str[i++] = res.getString("EMP_IDNUM");
 }
}
JComboBox jcb = new JComboBox(str);
```

Instead of array you can use Vector also to create JComboBox.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code:

```
Vector v = new Vector();
while(res.next()){
    String ids = res.getString("EMP_IDNUM");
    v.add(ids)
}
JComboBox jcb = new JComboBox(v);
```

In this code you create a `Vector` with your `Strings`, and then invoke directly the [`JComboBox(Vector items)` constructor of JComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#JComboBox%28java.util.Vector%29)

Answer (score 2):

there are three important areas

a) close all `JDBC Objects` in the `finally block`, because these `Object` aren't, never `GC'ed`

```
try {

} catch (Exception d) {
    System.out.println(d);
} finally {
    try {
        st.close()
        res.close() 
        dbcon.close()
    } catch (Exception d) {
        //not important
    }
}
```

b) don't to create any `Objects` inside `try - catch - finally`, prepare that before

meaning `cboId = new JComboBox(str);`

c) put all data from JDBC to the `ComboBoxModel`, prepare that before